# Have I rightly understood the use of pointers in my code?

Tags: c, pointers, stdin

I dont know if I've got it 100% right, but from what I've seen is that the &-operator means "the adress of" whatever variable I've assigned a pointer to. But I cant see how the use of pointers is favour me here. I mean, I guess I have got the right output as X = 5.0 and y = 50.0, But I cant really see the connection between the variables and pointers. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double *x, y;

    printf("Ange x: ", &x); // De-reference to the value of the standard input
    scanf("%lf", x);

    y = *x * 10;

    printf("%.1lf  %.1lf", *x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your understanding the first printf line in detail. Based on that, explaining your misunderstandings will be much clearer and easier.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong because `x` is dereferenced without being assigned a pointert to a valid buffer.

Also note that `&x` is not dereferencing but getting an address of the pointer variable `x`. This address is not used because there are not output specifier in the format `"Ange x: "`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
  double v;
  double *x, y;
  x = &v; // assign a valid address

  printf("Ange x: ", &x); // obtain an address of x (and have it ignore that)
  scanf("%lf", x);

  y = *x * 10;

  printf("%.1lf  %.1lf", *x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code didnt have the first print statement, thats something i tested out which gave me the right output,. Why do we ignore it?

Answer (score -1):

In your first printf, you used an & and said you de-referenced the x pointer. This is wrong, you need an * instead. If you print the address of a pointer, you will not get what the pointer holds but rather the memory address of it which may look something like "-726529380" but it will change every time you run it.

Also you need a "%d" in your first printf statement where you want x to be printed.

Comment: Using `%d` for printing `x` is bad. `%d` is for printing `int` but `x` is `double*`. Pointers should be printed via `%p`. Also Pointers should be caseted to `void*` for printing with `%p` because `%p` expects that.